# Not founding the actual last column

Tags: excel, vba

So i have this macro, this is just to order some stuff, but i got confused finding the last column cause even that i use the correct formula it doesn't found the actual last column, I know this because in a clear sheet it found perfectly the last column

Here's the obtained result

[image: Image1]

Now here's the code

```
Dim rcount, lastcol, lastrow, lastrow1 As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim strB As String

       lastcol = ActiveSheet.Cells("2", Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Rows.Count, "B"), Cells(Rows.Count, "E")).End(xlUp).Row
       lastrow1 = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Rows.Count, "B"), Cells(Rows.Count, "E")).End(xlUp).Row + 1
       
ActiveSheet.Range("B:E,J:K").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
ActiveSheet.Range("B2:E2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Range("E:E").Replace What:=",", Replacement:="."

With ActiveSheet
    rcount = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = rcount To 2 Step -1
            strB = Left(.Cells(i, "B").Value, 5)
            If strB = "PARTE" Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            Else
            End If
        Next i
    End With
With ActiveSheet
    rcount = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = rcount To 2 Step -1
            strB = Left(.Cells(i, "B").Value, 1)
            If strB = "S" Then
                .Cells(i + 1, lastcol).Value = "=1"
            Else
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

The number 1 must be in the column of 3s, but it is shifted, I don't know what could be,

Many thanks

Comment: You populate `lastcol` before deleting some columns?

Comment: After `ActiveSheet.Range("B:E,J:K").Delete` is execution, columns F:I will shift to left. The number 1 (originally located in column I) will move to column E. Last column and row should be populated after deletion and insertion.

Comment: Also you only need one loop - either delete the row, or populate the formula in `lastcol`.